# Android- Lower compile with API

Tags: android

Im new to android and I while selecting the compile with option while creating the android project i only get an option for 5.1.1. how do get lower api versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the lower api versions through Android SDK manager. 
You can find the SDK manager and information on how to work with it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).